# How to generate nHibernate raw sql for Insert/Update without execution?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Is it possible to generate a raw SQL statement for insert/update operations using nHibernate without actually executing them? Assuming of course that everything (mappings, connectionStrings, etc.) is properly configured?

The closest thing I've found is to call:

```
Session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(Client))
```

Which returns an object of type SingleTableEntityPersister containing SQLIdentityInsertString, that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Client (FirstName, LastName) values (?, ?)
```

But it would still require me to bind all of the properties manually, and on top of that SQLIdentityInsertString is a **protected** property. Are there any proper ways of doing that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need to import a large number of clients into the database from an XML file. There are multiple queries that need to be executed, but if I had a raw SQL for insert/update operations, I could do it with just one query. I have already tested it with a hardcoded SQL query, but that's of course not very maintainable (even though it did provide significant speed up). I'd like to generate the code in the runtime, using the exisitng nHibernate configuration and mappings rather than doing it manually.

Comment: I think there's a method on one of the interceptor interfaces or base classes that will give you SQL string that's going to be used: `OnPrepareStatement()`. You could tap into this but I think that you'd have to simulate the work first and then rollback the transaction.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `OnPrepareStatement()`, I've been using it for debugging purposes so far. In this case it would make the code way more confusing than it needs to be, so it's not really a viable solution.

Comment: You may try to grab the SQL from NHibernate log4net logs after an actual insert/update, then rollback the session. log4net allows to do that programmatically, see NHibernate tests [LogSpy](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.Test/LogSpy.cs) and [SqlLogSpy](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.Test/SqlLogSpy.cs). If you do have concurrently running sessions, it will of course not be reliable. A bit clunky though. If you manage to get it working, feel free to post it as an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the closest thing I've found is to construct your own sql query with a string builder. First you need to extract your class metadata:

```
var metaData = Session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(Client)) as SingleTableEntityPersister;
```

Then you can retrieve other information, such as:

```
var propertyNames = metaData.PropertyNames;
var tableName = metaData.TableName;
var firstPropertyValue = metaData.GetPropertyValue(client, propertyNames[0], EntityMode.Poco);
```

Once you have that information you can construct your own query manually. Not exactly the solution I wanted, but it's as close as it gets, I think.

However, one thing to note is that Session.CreateSQLQuery(string) method is currently bugged, and as a result SetParameter method doesn't work with more than 10 named parameters. There already seems to be a bug report created for this on NHbiernate's Jira.

Comment: Created just five hours ago: [NH-4053](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-4053).